Why Use the Passive Voice? An Example from Publicfan.com
On Publicfan.com, I noticed the sentence “Your content will be shared across platforms.” Why does this use the passive voice instead of saying “We will share your content across platforms”? What effect does this have on tone and clarity?

It's common practice to find the passive voice preferred in all kinds of settings where the speaker or agency wants to get the message across without being named, especially when apologies are due. Typically, one hears statements such as: Lessons have been learned; procedures have been improved; action has been taken. And so on.

I add to what Ronald said.
In the passive voice, the agent is unimportant or is chosen not to be mentioned.  In the OP's example, the message just states what will be done to your content.
Edit
I add the following points from Word Counter.  Use active voice when

you want to emphasize the action’s performer


your writing is non-scientific or does not require objectivity


you aim to keep your sentences simple and direct

Consider passive voice for

highlighting the object or action rather than the subject


making your writing more formal or objective, such as in scientific reports


when the action’s performer is unknown or unnecessary to mention

Word Counter
